# how can I change an image by hovering a button? More details below

Tags: javascript, html, hover

So basically I want to change an image by passing over the mouse on a button. with the current code I am able to change the image when the button is clicked, but I also need it to change when I put the mouse over the button without having to click it. Any ideas?

```
<body>
<input type="button" class = "button" onclick="changeImage('https://www.gettyimages.es/gi-resources/images/500px/983794168.jpg')" value="button1" />


<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8aHVtYW58ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" class = "img" id="firstimage" width="310">



<input type="button" class = "button4" onclick="changeImage('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8c3VucmlzZXxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80')" value="button2" />
```

and the javascript:

```
var image = document.getElementById('firstimage');

function changeImage(uri) {
  image.src = uri;
}
```

Comment: why dont you use onmouseover and get src by document.getElementById("").src

Comment: what? I didnt get it, can you explain it with more details?

Comment: On the image, just use the onmouseover event and then assign the js function to it.

Comment: You are making it really hard for yourself

Comment: Nothing don't worry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this?
like `onclick`, you can use `onmouseover` which is same as `:hover` in css

```js
var image = document.getElementById('firstimage');

function changeImage(uri) {
  image.src = uri;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class = "button" onclick="changeImage('https://www.gettyimages.es/gi-resources/images/500px/983794168.jpg')"

onmouseover="changeImage('https://www.gettyimages.es/gi-resources/images/500px/983794168.jpg')" 

value="button1" />


<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8aHVtYW58ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" class = "img" id="firstimage" width="310">



<input type="button" class = "button4" onclick="changeImage('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8c3VucmlzZXxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80')"

onmouseover="changeImage('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8c3VucmlzZXxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80')"  value="button2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, just give an Id to your Button, in order to get it after.

```
var button = document.getElementById("buttonId")
var image = document.getElementById('firstimage')


button.onmouseover = function(uri){
    image.src = uri
}
```